Generating a diagram on Wiki using tikz
I am trying to generate an image similar to:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncrossing_partition#/media/File:Noncrossing_partitions_5.svg
How can I can proceed?

Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as \documentclass{}...\begin{document} etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a minimal working example (MWE) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

And please include directly the image in your question.

The image you provide looks pretty much the same as in this Q&A.
